# Can I create dependent dropdown menu in XSLT without loading everything at once?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xml, xslt

I've created a dependent dropdown menu using JS and XSLT but in my solution I'm loading all data at once and then I filter it with JS. Is there a possibility of creating this same menu but in XSLT only? Or at least load dependent data only after launching a onChange event on select tag? I could do that with AJAX request but sadly I have to work with XML file as data source.

Little bit about menu itself - We start with selecting made of car, then we can select model of a car based on made, and then we can select type of model based on previously selected model.

My JS:

```
   //create global variables with data that was loaded in XSL file
    allMades = [...document.querySelector("#first-select").options];
    allModels = [...document.querySelector("#second-select").options];
    allTypes = [...document.querySelector("#third-select").options];

    //clear second and third select 
    $("#second-select").html("");
    $("#third-select").html("");

    //onchange handler for first select
    $("#first-select").change(({currentTarget})=>{
        //get value of changed select
        const madeId = $(currentTarget).val();
        //copy array of all models that was loaded at once in XSLT
        const arrayOfAllModels = [...allModels];
        //clear another selects
        $("#second-select").html("").append("<option>-</option>");
        $("#third-select").html("");
        //append models to second select that contains parent id
        arrayOfAllModels.map(item => {
           if(item.className.includes(`made-id-${madeId}`))   $("#second-select").append(item); 
        });
        //reset select 2 and 3 in case somebody change first select after changing second and third 
        $("#second-select").val("1");
        $("#third-select").val("1");
        $("#search-submit").removeAttr("href");

    });

    //onchange handler for second select
    $("#second-select").change(({currentTarget}) => {
        //get value of changed select
        const modelId = $(currentTarget).val();
        //copy array of all types that was loaded at once in XSLT
        const arrayOfAllTypes = [...allTypes];
        //clear third select
        $("#third-select").html("").append("<option>-</option>");
        //append types to third select that contains parent id
        arrayOfAllTypes.map(item => {
          if(item.className.includes(`model-id-${modelId}`))  $("#third-select").append(item);
        });
        $("#search-submit").removeAttr("href");
    });

    //onchange handler for third select
    $("#third-select").change(({currentTarget}) => {
        //get value of changed select
        const link = $(currentTarget).val();
        //append href to empty a tag
        $("#search-submit").attr("href", link);
    });
```

My XSL:

```
<div style="height:auto; width:100%; background-color:azure; position:absolute;" class="prototype-menu">
                                    <select style="min-width: 220px;" id="first-select">
                                    <option>-</option>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="navigation/item">
                                            <xsl:if test="item">
                                                <option><xsl:attribute name="class">made-id-<xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></option>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </select>

                                     <select style="min-width: 220px;"  id="second-select">
                                    <option>-</option>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="navigation/item/item">
                                            <xsl:if test="item">
                                                <option>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="@ni"/></xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="class">made-id-<xsl:value-of select="../@id"/> model-id-<xsl:value-of select="@ni"/></xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                                                </option>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </select>

                                    <select style="min-width: 220px;"  id="third-select">
                                    <option>-</option>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="navigation/item/item/item">
                                            <xsl:if test="item">
                                                <option>
                                                    
                                                <xsl:attribute name="class"> made-id-<xsl:value-of select="../../@id"/> model-id-<xsl:value-of select="../@ni"/> type-id-<xsl:value-of select="@ni"/>
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="@link"/></xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@link"/></xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/></option>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </select>
                                    <a style="margin-left: 30px; background: red;" id="search-submit">Search</a>
                            </div>
```

Please notice that this is only a prototype menu and I know that it's written poorly but I want to get this working, and then refractor/optimise code.

Comment: If  you want to use "only" XSLT you could look into Saxon-JS 2 providing XSLT 3 and interactive extension to handle HTML events, documentation is at https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/index.html, download at https://www.saxonica.com/download/javascript.xml and simplest example doing event handling from XSLT at https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/demos2/books/books.html. With XSLT 1 you can't handle events, if you don't want your XSLT to generate all `option` elements and populate the `select`s from the beginning perhaps only generate JS storing the relevant values.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thank you for your comment. I'm using external ecommerce service which is using XSLT 1.0 only. So I think my only way of doing that is actually what I did - getting all data in XSLT, and then store and filter that data in JS.

Comment: Unless your data is huge or frequently changes, I would say getting it all at once and filtering is the appropriate approach. Otherwise, you would have at least three AJAX calls to get the data and possibly many more if the person is changing selections in higher levels frequently.

Comment: @KevinBrown Thank you for response. I can't make AJAX calls because external ecommerce provider allows me to get data only through XSL file. So getting all at once is my only option.